# Exceptions with okHttp and SPDY

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, networking, okhttp

I have an Android Application using okHttp to do the communication with my server. I do some detailed error handling on the client side, reported to BugSense, and I've gotten a few confusing IOExceptions that I was hoping could be explained to me. The exceptions are:

```
1. stream was reset: CANCEL
2. connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
3. stream was reset: REFUSED_STREAM
4. Hostname 'myversion-dot-myapplication.appspot.com' was not verified
```

I don't recall seeing the first three before migrating to okHttp, specificlly the SPDY pieces. The last one is an issue that I have constantly struggled with on app engine (SSL provided by AppEngine seems to throw that error.)

I am checking for connectivity before initiating my transfer, so could this just be something that happens when connectivity is dropped while transferring? Is there something else that could cause this?

Thanks!

Evan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `stream was reset: CANCEL`: the SPDY stream was reset by either the local client or the remote peer. For example, the server may cancel a connection because it has crashed or is restarting.
- `connect failed: ENETUNREACH`: your SPDY server isn't reachable. Perhaps it has disappeared since you did your connectivity check.
- `stream was reset: REFUSED STREAM`: the remote server does not want to accept this connection, possibly because it is shutting down.
- `Hostname 'myversion-dot-myapplication.appspot.com' was not verified`: the HTTPS certificate presented by the remote peer is not trusted by any of the root certificates on the requesting device.

Comment: Thanks Jesse! I sort of suspected something like this. So you think it's safe to ignore the top three errors? I have another S/O about the AppEngine certificate but nobody has been able to help there.

Comment: Yeah, you can ignore the top three.