# What causes "java.io.IOException: stream was reset: CANCEL" with okhttp and spdy?

Tags: java, android, networking, spdy, okhttp

I'm experimenting with OKHttp (version 2.0.0-RC2) and SPDY and seeing `IOException: stream was reset: CANCEL` quite a lot, maybe 10% or more of all requests in some preliminary testing. When using Apache HttpClient and regular https we were not seeing any equivalent issue as far as I'm aware. I'm pretty sure we also don't see anything equivalent with OkHttp when SPDY is disabled (`client.setProtocols(ImmutableList.of(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))`) but I haven't done enough testing to be 100% confident.

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926538/exceptions-with-okhttp-and-spdy) sees these exceptions among others and the advice there is to ignore them, but this seems crazy: we get an exception while reading data from the server, so we abort the data processing code (which using Jackson). We need to do *something* in such cases. We could retry the request, of course, but sometimes it's a POST request which is not retry-able, and if we've already started receiving data from the server then it's a good bet that the server as already taken the requested action.

Ideally there is some configuration of the client and/or the server that we can do in order to reduce the incidence of these exceptions, but I don't understand SPDY well enough to know even where to start looking or to advise our server-admin team to start looking.

Stack trace, in case it's helpful:

```
java.io.IOException: stream was reset: CANCEL
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.spdy.SpdyStream$SpdyDataSource.checkNotClosed(SpdyStream.java:442)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.spdy.SpdyStream$SpdyDataSource.read(SpdyStream.java:344)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.SpdyTransport$SpdySource.read(SpdyTransport.java:273)
  at okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.java:60)
  at okio.InflaterSource.refill(InflaterSource.java:96)
  at okio.InflaterSource.read(InflaterSource.java:62)
  at okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.java:80)
  at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:227)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.loadMore(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:174)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.loadMoreGuaranteed(ParserBase.java:431)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishString2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2111)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishString(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2092)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.getText(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:275)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:205)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeArray(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:230)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:202)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:58)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:15)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2765)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:1546)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.readValueAsTree(JsonParser.java:1363)
  at (application-level code...)
```

Comment: Any idea which webserver you're talking to? It's possible that there's a protocol error on our side or the server's.

Comment: What are your request timeouts set at?

Comment: @JesseWilson we're talking to CloudFlare, which uses some build of nginx, and the request timeouts are:

cli.setConnectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); cli.setReadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to set a breakpoint in the two places where the CANCEL error code is assigned: that's `SpdyStream#closeInternal` (line 246) and `SpdyStream#receiveRstStream` (line 304). If you can put a breakpoint here, you can capture *who* is canceling your stream and that'll shed light on the problem.

If for whatever reason you cannot attach a debugger, you can instrument the code to print a stacktrace when those lines are reached:

```
new Exception("SETTING ERROR CODE TO " + errorCode).printStackTrace();
```

In either case, I'm the author of that code and I'd love to help you resolve this problem.

Comment: …and now that I *want* the CANCEL error code to come up, I can't reproduce it. I'll take a look a bit more over the next couple days, thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I am using OkHttp 2.4.0-RC1 in an upcoming Android project, and I have lots of CANCEL errors when using the Android M preview emulator (x86). Interestingly, if I activate the debugger, most of the network requests suddenly go through correctly - could be a race condition? Here is how an exception looks like: http://pastebin.com/AwGssiZg (I am using Volley for now, but I might switch to Retrofit later)

Comment: @mreichelt the same advice applies. Put a breakpoint in the code wherever errorCode is assigned.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm curious if you found a solution here. I'm in the same situation, where Cloudflare is in front of my server adding the SPDY items (our backend doesn't serve it, older version of NGINX).

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and this was a result of network connection timeout, this was a result of downloading a large file from the web service 
i had my timeout set to 2-min so i changed it to 5-min and it solved my problem

```
val  okkHttpclient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
   .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // write timeout
    .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // read timeout
    .addInterceptor(networkConnectionInterceptor)
    .build()
```

Comment: This helped me with `OkHttpClient`, but still can't get it with `RestTemplate`

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue because of broken http headers. The android Base64 encoder by default adds newlines which broke our Authorization headers.

Comment: I was seeing this error with okhttp v3.11.0 because I wasn't specifying a correct API key required by our servers.